# I want to add group product by custom method but I just ending up adding last product from 3 grouped Item in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

Here what I trying to add group product through customize button, I get all 3 products id and quantity but when I send to my custom add to cart, its only last item added in cart not all 3. below is my code

```
let groupedProductElements = document.getElementsByClassName('woocommerce-grouped-product-list-item');
                let j =0;
                var pr_len =  groupedProductElements.length;
                [...groupedProductElements].forEach(function (i){
                    let productId =i.getAttribute('id');
                    let id = productId.split('-');
                    let product_id = id[1];
                    let quantity = i.children[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
                    let variation_id = product_id;
                    cartData[j] ={
                        "product_id": product_id,
                        "variation_id": variation_id,
                        "quantity": quantity
                    }

                        formData.append("product_id",product_id);
                        formData.append("variation_id", variation_id);
                        formData.append("quantity", quantity);
                });
                for(j=0; j<cartData.length; j++){
                    formData.append("action", "my_add_to_cart");
                }
```

I am new in wordpress plugin and woocommerce plugin development please help. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your ```forEach```, ```cartData[j]``` "j" is always going to be ```0```. You need to add ```1``` to it at the end of ```forEach```. After last ```formData.append```, I would add ```j++```.

Comment: Hi Ruvee Thanks for you suggestion but I have increased J++ after formData.append. but its not working. its showing 3 product id, 3 quanity and my action in my header of ajax call but its not working anyhow. If you have any more Idea please share